# LWC & Aura Coding Standards

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, bestpractice

I want to ask if somewhere I can find best practices how to develop in LWC and Aura? Salesforce has prepare that kind of document for Apex:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

but I don' see similar for LWC or Aura.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, We have some very good documentation on Aura component best practice:-

1. [Lightning Components Performance Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/lightning-components-performance-best-practices.html)
2. [Securing Data in Apex Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_crud_fls.htm)

For Lightning Web Component, Watch this Youtube session by [René Winkelmeyer](https://twitter.com/muenzpraeger) here:-

[Lightning Web Components Best practices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjSlkU6Z6bs&t=153s)

Some of them are:-

1. Using public, and private properties for effective component
   composition. When we should use @api or @track variable
2. Event communication for child-to-parent as well as for sibling
   components (pubsub). Parent to Child Communication and Child to Parent Communication
3. pubsub : When, and when not, to use Apex with Lightning Web Components
   UI Record Api in LWC
4. Lightning Data Service in LWC (Lightning record form)
5. Aura interoperabilitys Recipes, Patterns and Best Practices
6. How to debug Lightning Web Components
7. How to test Lightning Web Component (Lightning Testing Service) - Jest Tests for Lightning Web Components ( LTS )

Comment: Thanks sanket kumar!